# facebook plugin in ionic cordova vesrsion7.1.1

Tags: firebase, facebook, twitter, push-notification

I have been trying to integrate facebook login into my ionic app and as well twitter and as well firebase push notifications:
in this for firebase plugin im getting error as 'plugin not installed ' even i have added plugin with latest fcm-with-dependency and as well for facebook plugin able to get error page as 'login disabled' even after follow all steps to unbock.

for facebook login:
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook --variable APP_ID="my_app_id" --variable APP_NAME="DTCProject"
npm install --save @ionic-native/facebook
for firebase push notifications:
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated
npm install @ionic-native/fcm
and :
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex
npm install @ionic-native/firebase-x
thesere are i have tried to use pliugins but as result of not getting results as we expected.

And my ionic info is:
Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 7.1.1
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 7.5.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 16.1.0
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 16.1.0
@angular/cli                  : 16.1.0
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 9.0.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 12.0.0 (cordova-lib@12.0.1)
Cordova Platforms : android 10.1.2 / (and tried with 12.0.0)
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 9 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.15.4
native-run  : 2.0.0

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
NodeJS            : v20.10.0
npm               : 10.2.3
OS                : Windows 10